# JavaMail : Get folder name doesn't work

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I use JavaMail and protocol imap to organize email (gmail).
I create a folder FOLDER1 with the code :

```
Folder newFolder = parent.getFolder(folderName);
if (!newFolder.exists())
    isCreated = newFolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
```

I move the message with the code :

```
Folder f = store.getFolder(folderName);
Message[] msgs = { msg };
f.appendMessages(msgs);
```

it works

but I don't understand ... when I want to read again the messages but not the messages already read and not in the folder already created it doesn't work.
The name is already INBOX

```
String folderName = message.getFolder().getName();// INBOX!! and not FOLDER1
String fullName = message.getFolder().getFullName();// INBOX!! and not INBOX/FOLDER1
```

What's the problem ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The **content** of the Message object is appended to the other folder.  The Message object itself continues to refer to the message in the original folder.  To find the copy of the message in the other folder, you need to open the other folder and search for it

Using the [IMAPFolder.copyUIDMessages](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#copyUIDMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.Folder-) method you can get the UID of the message in the other folder, then open the other folder and use the [UIDFolder.getMessageByUID](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessageByUID-long-) method to get the Message object representing the message in the other folder.  (An IMAP Folder object always implements the UIDFolder interface.)

Comment: but why getFolder("inbox") return all messages (with others folders)?

Comment: If you copy the message to another folder and don't delete it from the INBOX folder, it's still going to be in the INBOX folder.

Comment: but it's com.sun.mail.pop3 not javax.mail ? that's a problem ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but if you're using pop3 instead of imap there are **a lot** of limitations, including the fact that pop3 only supports the single INBOX folder and no other folders.  See also the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmailsettings).

Comment: I use imap .. I'm going to do again my question